# 18.04.2 Emojis partially gone from Librewriter autocorrect

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, emoji

Completed a fresh install and update of 18.04.2 64-bit last week.

It's perfectly fine. Except many emojis are gone from whatever Noto pack Librewriter uses. I'd like them back. Included below is a picture of the issue.

As you can see, it calls the location of the emoji just fine, but there doesn't seem to be any data in that part of the font pack that Librewriter would care to display. Not a � but a tall empty rectangle replaces most my emojis.

This is also the case in all my `.odt` docs. They have an empty rectangle where the emojis used to be before this fresh install, update, and restart.

gedit displays emojis from `Right Click > Insert Emoji` just fine.

I have no idea what information you need, but i hope this is a good start.

[example missing emojis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuw79.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 added official support for color emoji with the addition of Google Noto Color Emoji.  In previous versions, color emoji wasn't included and would have to have been a user-installed font or package.

Google has [installation instructions](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/install/) for their font pack.

You could also install the `ttf-ancient-fonts` package through Synaptic or apt, which adds emoji support.

Comment: Damn, Google, that's a Gig of fonts. Alright. `fc-cache` just stared at that file for like forever. Still nothing changes in Librewriter.

Installing `ttf-ancient-fonts` now. That did it! All my emoji friends are back. You are wonderful.

Comment: I had excluded all fonts except NotoSans and NotoSerif in `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`. I have now added `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoColorEmoji` to the accept list :)